# Column Aliasing raised error: no such column

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

This query is working expectedly in Mysql:

```
SELECT category AS category_name, COUNT(id) AS total_books,
(SELECT COUNT(language) FROM books WHERE language = 'lang1' AND category = category_name) AS lang1,
(SELECT COUNT(language) FROM books WHERE language = 'lang2' AND category = category_name) AS lang2,
(SELECT COUNT(language) FROM books WHERE language = 'lang3' AND category = category_name) AS lang3
FROM books GROUP BY category
```

But in SQLite it is raising error: **room [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: category_name)**

Why is this happening? Does SQLite requires different approach than Mysql for this query?

Comment: Why downvote? I have searched possibly many sites from last 2 days before posting the question here but didn't found anything that could solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL appears to be more lax in its allowed usage of aliases.  You may try rewriting your query using more explicit aliases as this:

```
SELECT
    category AS category_name,
    COUNT(id) AS total_books,
    (SELECT COUNT(language) FROM books b2
     WHERE language = 'lang1' AND b2.category = b1.category) AS lang1,
    (SELECT COUNT(language) FROM books b2
     WHERE language = 'lang2' AND b2.category = b1.category) AS lang2,
    (SELECT COUNT(language) FROM books b2
     WHERE language = 'lang3' AND b2.category = b1.category) AS lang3
FROM books b1
GROUP BY category;
```

But a better way to perhaps write this would replace your correlated subqueries with conditional aggregations:

```
SELECT
    category AS category_name,
    COUNT(id) AS total_books,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'lang1' THEN 1 END) AS lang1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'lang2' THEN 1 END) AS lang2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'lang3' THEN 1 END) AS lang3
FROM books
GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I understand your first query writing but I didn't understand how the second one is working, little bit hard to understand. Can you please explain how CASE is working without usage of category_name. Thanks :)

Comment: @SharoonAmjid count counts items. CASE specifies a condition. As a parameter to the count it specifies a value. Since other cases are not included, it will not count mismatches to the count.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thank you for explaining.  This syntax looks very neat and tidy.